# ng:areq fn is not a function got objectService angularjs es6

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, ecmascript-6

I have 1 service which extends other. When I try to import it in controller got this error ng:areq fn is not a function got UserRepository. I think my problem is in right way injecting this service. Here is my Service:

```
import { USER_REPO_CONFIG } from '../repository.config';
import { AbstractRepository } from '../abstract.repository';
import { UserModel } from './user.model';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

class UserRepository extends AbstractRepository {
    constructor($http) {
        'NgInject'
        super($http, USER_REPO_CONFIG, UserModel);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the user by ID
     * 
     * @param {number} userId - ID of a user to find
     * @returns {Observable<UserModel>} - User model instance
     */
    getUser(userId) {
        return this.getItem(userId);
    }

    /**
     * Creates the user
     * 
     * @param {UserModel} user - User model instance
     * @returns {Observable<UserModel>} - User model instance observable
     */
    createUser(user) {
        return this.createItem(user);
    }

    /**
     * Updates the user
     * 
     * @param {number} userId - ID of a user to update
     * @param {UserModel} user - User model instance
     * @returns {Observable<UserModel>} - User model instance observable
     */
    updateUser(userId, user) {
        return this.updateItem(userId, user);
    }
}

export { UserRepository };
```

here is my Module:

```
import { HelloComponent } from './hello/hello.component';
import { UserRepository } from '../core/repository/user/user.repository';

const greetingModule = angular
                     .module('app.greeting',[])
                     .component('helloComponent', new HelloComponent)
                     .service('UserRepository', new UserRepository)
                     .name;

export { greetingModule };
```

and my Controller:

```
import { UserRepository } from '../../core/repository/user/user.repository';

class HelloController {
    constructor(UserRepository) {
        this.hello = 'Hello World';
        this.service = UserRepository;
    }

    getAll() {
        console.log('user Repository', this.service)
    }
}
HelloController.$inject = ['UserRepository'];
export { HelloController };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.service('UserRepository', new UserRepository)
```

`.service()` expects a function, you pass an object. You can pass the class directly:

```
.service('UserRepository', UserRepository)
```

Passing the class effectively passes the constructor function.